# Publish content on Facebook via RSS

Tags: facebook, rss, facebook-page

I would like to add new content via some API. I found [this site](http://boomient.com/seo-blog/how-to-import-blog-to-facebook-rss) where they say that there is a *Imported Sites* function which allows to enter a RSS feed and the content will be posted automatically. Is this true? Or better does that work today too?

If yes please point me where I have to set that. Facebook has changed in such a way that [their way](http://boomient.com/seo-blog/how-to-import-blog-to-facebook-rss) doesn't work today. Im looping thrue the menus since about a hour without any success.

If this does not work please show me a other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since September, this feature has been removed.

> We want you to connect with your fans in the most effective ways possible. That's why as of September 30th you'll no longer be able to automatically import posts from your website to your Page notes. The best way to get people to interact with your content is to give them insight into the links you share on your Wall by adding personal comments and responding to feedback from fans.

[Source: Why can I no longer import blog posts from my website to my Page's notes?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=277347965620183)